execution fails but I could not understand why
declare
l_statement varchar2(2000);

date2 date:= to_date('29-02-2024','dd-mm-yyyy');

begin
l_statement := 'delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date =' || date2;
execute immediate l_statement;

exception 
when others then
raise;

end;
/

Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 12
ORA-06512: at line 8
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:


That's because statement you're executing is invalid.
Sample data:
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee_tab
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 125 id, DATE '2024-02-29' joined_date FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 555, TRUNC (SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;

Table created.

SQL> set serveroutput on

Instead of executing it blindly, I'm displaying the statement:
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_statement  VARCHAR2 (2000);
  3
  4     date2        DATE := TO_DATE ('29-02-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
  5  BEGIN
  6     l_statement := 'delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date =' || date2;
  7
  8     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line (l_statement);
  9  --   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement;
 10  EXCEPTION
 11     WHEN OTHERS
 12     THEN
 13        RAISE;
 14  END;
 15  /
delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date =29.02.24

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

Can you run it? Nope:
SQL> delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date =29.02.24;
delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date =29.02.24
                                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL>

Don't concatenate date value; bind it.
Sample data (once again):
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From employee_tab;

        ID JOINED_DAT
---------- ----------
       125 29.02.2024
       555 19.06.2024

Your new code; pay attention to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE!
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_statement  VARCHAR2 (2000);
  3
  4     date2        DATE := TO_DATE ('29-02-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
  5  BEGIN
  6     l_statement := 'delete from employee_tab where id=125 and joined_date = :a';
  7
  8     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement
  9        USING date2;
 10  EXCEPTION
 11     WHEN OTHERS
 12     THEN
 13        RAISE;
 14  END;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Result:
SQL> select * from employee_tab;

        ID JOINED_DAT
---------- ----------
       555 19.06.2024

SQL>

Right; row has been deleted.
